# How is Apple applying overflow:hidden to elements inside of position:fixed?

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position

Based on my own tests and researching the topic on the internet, elements with `position: fixed` don't respect a parent element's `overflow: hidden` property. This includes children of the `fixed` position element — because they are within the `fixed` positioned element, they don't respect the ancestor's `overflow: hidden` property either.

However, Apple is somehow getting around this on [Apple Music](http://www.apple.com/music:)

**Containing element with `overflow: hidden`**

[image]

**Inner element with `position: fixed`**

[image]

**The phone itself**

[image]

You can see by the blue highlight in the second image that the `fixed` positioned element does indeed overflow its container, as does the phone inside it (3rd image). Yet, the contents of the `fixed` positioned element (the phone) still gets clipped by the ancestor with `overflow: hidden`. Using Chrome's dev tools, if I remove the `overflow: hidden` property from that ancestor, the entire phone indeed appears.

How is Apple doing this? I have tried recreating it with the same combination of fixed, relative, overflow, etc. settings, but I'm clearly missing something because I haven't been successful.

## UPDATE

As @user3790069 points out in his answer, a `fixed` positioned element can be clipped by a relatively positioned one if the relatively positioned element has a higher `z-index`, or simply comes after the `fixed` position one (and is thus given a higher z-index by default). However, in the Apple Music example, the `overflow: hidden` property still seems to be the key they're relying on. To test this, I removed a bunch of the DOM to reduce clutter. What we're left with in the following screenshots are:

a) a containing `section` element with `overflow: hidden`
b) inside of that, a `position: fixed` element.

In the first screenshot, you'll see that the phone is clipped. In the second screenshot, I removed the `overflow: hidden` property and suddenly the overflowing part of the phone becomes visible.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't find the fixed element on the linked page

Comment: I've added an additional image showing the phone.

Comment: I found a solution, but I'm not sure if the page that you linked uses my method. Do I post it?

Comment: Please do! I'm most interested in achieving the effect, whether it's the precise approach Apple took or not.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm going to explain why aren't fixed children clipped by `overflow: hidden` on their parent. A box **B** is clipped by `overflow` applied to its ancestor **A** only if **A** is the containing block of **B**. But [the containing block](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visudet.html#containing-block-details) of a fixed element isn't a simple ancestor; a containing block of something with `position: fixed` is the whole [wiewport](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html#viewport).

I think that the fixed elements on the linked page aren't really cut by `overflow`; they're rather hidden under other positioned elements.

**[An exemple](http://cssdeck.com/labs/jogobzmf)**:

```
<div id=cont>
  <div style="background: red">
    <div class=fixed></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background: yellow">
    <div class=fixed id=second></div>
  </div>
    <div style="background: green"></div>
</div>

#cont {
  height: 5000px
}

#cont > div {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative
}

.fixed {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px
}

#second {
  top: 240px
}
```

Comment: Good catch, although Apple does seem to be relying on the `overflow: hidden` property of the containing element. See the update to my post.